# Enhnaced ecommerce google analytics code for add to cart

Tags: google-analytics

This is code for add to cart in enhanced ecommerce feature of google analytics.

```
function addToCarts() {
    ga('ec:addProduct', {
        'id': '12334',
        'name': 'methyly methly',
        'category': 'Clothing',
        'brand': '',
        'variant': '',
        'price': '100',
        'quantity': 40
    });
    ga('ec:setAction', 'add');
    // send this using event
    ga('send', 'event', 'enhanced ecommerce', 'button click', 'add to cart');
}
addToCarts();
```

This is reflected in Conversions-->Ecommerce-->Product performace's Add to cart metrics.
Please see attached image.

Here i am setting default value of quantity to 40 but still 'Products Add to cart' metrics only increments it by 1 in google analytics.

Just to confirm that 40 quantity is sent or not i checked from developers tool and quantity is sent 40 only but still in google analytics  'Products Add to cart' metrics only increments it by 1 in google analytics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I confirm that that column indicates the **number of times the product was added to the shopping cart**, not the quantity of product added to the cart. You can find the quantity in Summary tab of the same report.

Comment: thankyou is there any way i could figure out how many quantity for each product were added too.

Comment: what i mean is that in summary section i can only find quantity of transaction but not of add to cart.How to figure that out.Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63051804/google-analytics-add-to-cart-quantity