# Google analytics add to cart quantity

Tags: google-analytics

We use this code format in google analytics corresponding to add to cart feature of google analytics.

```
function addToCarts() {
    ga('ec:addProduct', {
        'id': '12334',
        'name': 'methyly methly',
        'category': 'Clothing',
        'brand': '',
        'variant': '',
        'price': '100',
        'quantity': 40
    });
    ga('ec:setAction', 'add');
    // send this using event
    ga('send', 'event', 'enhanced ecommerce', 'button click', 'add to cart');
}
addToCarts();
```

Where in google analtics convertion tab----->Enhanced ecommerce i can see quantity of product added?.Their is one section in google analytics conversion---->Enhanced ecommerce--->shopping behaviour--->Products add to cart(metric). But it only reflect how many times product was added to cart but not how many qunatity of that product to cart.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enhnaced ecommerce google analytics code for add to cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63031040/enhnaced-ecommerce-google-analytics-code-for-add-to-cart)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the quantity in Summary tab of the report: Conversions-->Ecommerce-->Product performace (Summary tab).